# Azure App Configuration to retrieve configuration values from c# Azure function via Managed Identity is not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I have created Azure App configuration and sets Key and value pairs. I have also created a HTTP Azure function via VS 2019 and write below code.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Azure.Identity;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.Connect(new Uri("https://xxx-xxx-azf-global-parameters.azconfig.io"),
    new ManagedIdentityCredential());
}).Build();
string str = config["AzfApp:Cloud"].ToString();
log.LogInformation("AzfApp:Cloud:" + config["AzfApp:Cloud"].ToString());
```

Enable System assigned Identity of Azure Function. The identity I am using via ManagedIdentityCredential is assigned to both the Azure App Configuration Data Reader and Azure App Configuration Data Owner roles. But above my code is not working Azure portal. I have capture the error via log information.

> Error message :Retry failed after 3 tries. (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.)Source=Azure.CoreStackTrace:at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.

Please help on this how do I resolve the issue.

Comment: It seems your URI endpoint is incorrect or Managed Identity does not have `App Configuration Data Reader` role.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you ,please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site with your code and it works very well.
[image]

Go to azure app configuration and double check that you have assign  `Azure App Configuration Data Reader` to the function's Identity.

[image]

And the output screenshot is as below:

[image]